# Renaming already existing files

Tags: php

Currently I am working on a media uploader system.
When a user uploads files, I wanted the system to automatically check whether this file already exists, and if so, add a (x) to the basename.

`DSC_2193.jpg` would become `DSC_2193 (1).jpg`

`DSC_2193 (2).jpg` would become `DSC_2193 (3).jpg`

So I came up with the following function:

```
<?php
private function setFileName($path)
{
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $file = pathinfo($path);
        if (preg_match('/\(([0-9]+)\).' . $file['extension'] . '/', $file['basename'], $matches)) {
            return $this->setFileName($file['dirname'] . '/' . preg_replace_callback('/\(([0-9]+)\).' . $file['extension'] . '/', function($matches)
            {
                return '(' . ($matches[1] + 1) . ')';
            }, $file['basename']) . '.' . $file['extension']);
        } else {
            $basename = substr(basename($path, $file['extension']), 0, -1);
            $basename .= ' (1).' . $file['extension'];
            return $this->setFileName($file['dirname'] . '/' . $basename);
        }
    }

    else
        return $path;
}
?>
```

Now I was wondering: would this be the right approach to achieve this? If not: maybe someone can come up with a better alternative. If it is the most efficient way, maybe someone benefits from this.

Comment: Keep in mind, that it wouldn't work the way you expect if user uploaded file with UTF-8 string. So for example, if `$_FILES['field_name']['name'] == 'здраво.jpg'` then a file will be broken and handled wrong

Comment: Hmmm, I did not think of that. Would there be any way to prevent it? Except from replacing the filename with a timestamp or something similar.

Comment: No, a best practice here is to rename files (Like FB devs do). You can rename each file with `uniqid()`. That would ensure: 1) A filename isn't longer than 255 bytes 2) A filename doesn't contain malicious code (like html tags) 3) It only has ASCII chars, so therefore will never be broken, regarding its Japanese, or Cyrillic encoding

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using `while` cycle. Here is simple scratch:

```
private function setFileName($path)
{
    $file = pathinfo($path);

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $i = 1;
        while (file_exists($file['filename'] . ' (' . $i . ').' . $file['extension'])) $i++;

        $filename = $file['filename'] . ' (' . $i . ').' . $file['extension']; // don't know if you want also directory path
    }
    else
        $filename = $file['filename'] . '.' . $file['extension'];

    // some code to rename/move_uploaded_file...       
}
```

I don't know what you want then if you have `$filename` set (`move_uploaded_file`, or just `return $filename`), so the rest of code is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your share. However, I decided to go with djay's advice. In the long run it seems like the smarter choice.

Comment: Of course, I also prefer using uniqid, I just answered on your task about using number after same name of the file.